# Problems with JSON and MySQL

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I want to make a simple activity which gets only one value from the database(there's only 1 in it).
But I have one big Problem. I always get the same Error in LogCat: "Error parsing data.org.json.JSONException: Value 1nulln of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray. "
Here's my code:

```
public class DailyQ extends Activity {
    InputStream is;
    String quest;
    JSONObject json_data;
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.daily_q);
            getData();

     }


            public void getData() {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
                        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                        .permitAll().build(); 
                        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

                String result = "";
                     ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                     try{
                     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://domain.com/file.php");
                 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
             is = entity.getContent();
                     }catch(Exception e){
                 Log.e("log_tag", "Fehler bei der http Verbindung "+e.toString());
                     }
                     try{
                             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                             String line = null;
                             while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                             sb.append(line + "n");
                             } 
                             is.close();
                          result=sb.toString();
                             }catch(Exception e){
                             Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());

                             }
                     try{
                             JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                             for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                             json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                             int id = json_data.getInt("day");
                             quest = json_data.getString("question");                        
                             TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                           tv.setText(quest);
                             } 

                             }
                             catch(JSONException e){
                          Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                             }
                            }
            }
```

And this is the PHP File:

```
<?php
mysql_connect(...) or die ("Keine Verbindung");
mysql_select_db("...);

$q=mysql_query("SELECT day,question FROM quest");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
$output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output));
 mysql_close();
?>
```

I have looked in so many threads but I can't find an answer. Are you having an answer?

Thank you in advance and sorry for my English(I'm a pupil from Germany)

Comment: Please post your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe your `result` is a json encoded string and therefore your JSONArray function is failing:

Check out the [requirements for your JSONArray function](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html)

JSON strings should look something like [this](http://json.org/example):

```
{"1": "1_data", "2": "2_data", "3": "3_data"}
```

---

You could probably just append `{` to the front and `}` to the back of `result` and it will probably work.